# Socket.io clients keep reconnecting on Azure host

Tags: node.js, azure, express, socket.io

I'm hosting a small node.js app in azure, but when a client is joined it gets reconnected almost immediately and this is keep going on!

If i switch "Web Sockets" on in Azure, the reconnections are gone, but it doesn't seem to recieve any disconnect event if i close the clients*, also the connection events are registered relatively slow as well!

*disconnect events do get registered after a minute delay!

If i run the app in local, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share any code or `web.config` file with us. However, there is an official instruction: [Create a Node.js chat application with Socket.IO in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio) we can follow.

You may need to pay attention to [Verify web.config settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio#troubleshooting):

> Azure web apps that host Node.js applications use the **web.config**
>   file to route incoming requests to the Node.js application. For
>   WebSockets to function correctly with Node.js applications, the
>   **web.config** must contain the following entry.
>
> ```
> <webSocket enabled="false"/>
> ```
>
> This disables the IIS WebSockets module, which includes its own
>   implementation of WebSockets and conflicts with Node.js specific
>   WebSocket modules such as Socket.IO. If this line is not present, or
>   is set to `true`, this may be the reason that the WebSocket transport
>   is not working for your application.

Comment: I didn't share web.config file since i dind't made any i can't access the auto-generated one! However as i have mentioned i had to enable web sockets on the dashboard to prevent the continous reconnection!